# Why does "Set Network Location" pop up every time I connect with VZAccess Manager?

Tags: windows-7, wwan

I've got a Toshiba netbook with Windows 7 Starter and a Pantech UM175VW USB modem. Every time I connect through VZAccess Manager, "Set Network Location" pops up and asks the following:

> Select a location for the 'Verizon Wireless - VZAccess ##' network
>
> [Home network]
>
> [Work network]
>
> [Public network]

Where ## increments every time I connect (it's now up to 17).  Clearly, Windows sees the connection as belonging to a new wireless network every time I connect.  Is there any way to prevent Windows from popping up these "Set Network Location" prompts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably connecting to different routers -- it happens to me at my school too, when I move around and connect to a different router for the same network.

There's a "Always select Public and don't ask me again" checkbox (paraphrased here, I don't remember the text) at the bottom, which you might want to check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you must be right about the network being identified on a per-router basis, which I guess will change depending on which cell tower I happen to connect to. I wasn't crazy about the idea of keeping a list of all the different WWAN routers I connect to, but now that I think about it, I can see why it's done.  It would be nice to be able to automatically treat all VZAccess connections as public yet still get the "Select Network Location" prompt for, say, 802.11 or wired networks.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it would be nice to do that... I've been annoyed by the same thing. But hey, there's only a finite number of connections... eventually it'll stop showing that dialog, huh? :)